# Display current week events only in calendar webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to display current week Events only in calendar webpart in shapoint 2010. 
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply use the week view in your calendar?

Answer (score 0):

To filter a list to show the current week’s items or events, create two calculated columns with a data type of Date and Time (Date Only), and a view with filters based on the new columns.

I’ve included the formulas and view filters below.  [Visit my blog post](https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/show-this-week-only/) on this topic for a more in-depth explanation and to view screenshots.

Column 1 Name:  Calc_WeekViewEnd
Column 1 Formula:  =[End Time]-WEEKDAY([End Time],2)+7

Column 2 Name:  Calc_WeekViewStart
Column 2 Formula:  =[Calc_WeekViewEnd]-7

View Name:  This Week
View Filters:  Calc_WeekViewStart is less than or equal to [Today], AND, Calc_WeekViewEnd is greater than or equal to [Today]

Answer (score 0):

Modify the view and set the scope to display week instead of month. By default it will show the current day / week.